# Build fails in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, gradle

I installed Android Studio 4.1 recently, tried to run a sample project in Android Studio 4.1. Got this error:

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)

So I modified few lines as given below:

1. Changed `gradle.properties` as
   `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
   to
   `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
2. Updated `minSdkVersion` to `21`
3. Added `Multidex` support

   def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
   implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"

I even tried `invalidate caches and restart`.

My classspath is `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"` and gradle version is `gradle-6.5`.

I made sure that Android Studio 4.1 meets minimum compatibility as given in [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#compatibility).

Then I tried to install the sample app in device. I got this error:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)

What is causing this? Is this a bug?

Comment: Have you tried  `File > Sync Project with Gradle Files` ?

Comment: @Omkar76 Yes, did that... Getting this error: `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: app\build\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug`

Answer (score 9):

I managed to fix it...
You have 3 options to fix that error (Error in question)

1. Add Multidex Support
   Add these lines in `dependencies`

   def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
   implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
   Add this line to `defaultConfig`:
   `multiDexEnabled true`
   Sync your project, see if that fixes your error.
2. If option 1 doesn't work, try increasing `jvmargs`
   Add this line in `gradle.properties`:
   `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
   Sync and run your project.
3. If both options don't work, then delete `.gradle` and `build` folder in your project's directory. Run `Clean project` and `Rebuild project`. Then run the project.
   **NOTE:** If above options doesn't work, then `invalidate caches and restart`.

Comment: Number 3 fixed it for me, Just a clean and a rebuild, it was the first thing to try

Comment: 1st option worked for me. Thanks Ajay.
Already i had this line  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'. 
Added these lines, working fine
def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"

Answer (score 0):

delete output path of apk files, ex: app/build/outputs/apk